# Unable to get wp_get_attachment_url to show

Tags: attachments, images

I'm trying to show a link to the full size image of an attached image. I took a code for Wordpress' Twelve Thirteen theme:

```
<?php 
$metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata();
printf( '<span class="attachment-meta full-size-link"><a href="%1$s" rel="lightbox">%3$s</a></span>',
esc_url( wp_get_attachment_url() ),
esc_attr__( 'Link to full-size image'),
__( 'View Full Size' ),
$metadata['array'],
                                $metadata['array']
);
?>
```

It shows on the twelve thirteen theme with a magnifying class and the text 'Full Resolution (width x height). It doesn't show the theme 'terrifico' I'm using. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That's not going to work, instead just use `wp_get_attachment_image_src` , it takes a size parameter.

```
// get the $attachment_id
$attach_stuff = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full');
var_dump($attach_stuff);
```

You will be returned an array fo values to work with:

```
[0] => url
[1] => width
[2] => height
[3] => boolean: true if $url is a resized image, false if it is the original.
```

Also turn on [**debugging.**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Answer (score 0):

The below code will get you the full image url. You can use the `wp_get_attachment_image`  to get it.

```
<?php 
  $metadata = wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'full');
  printf( '<span class="attachment-meta full-size-link"><a href="%1$s" rel="lightbox">%3$s</a></span>',
  esc_url( $metadata ),
  esc_attr__( 'Link to full-size image'), __( 'View Full Size' ) );
?>
```

if you don't have attachment's ID than use this [article](http://www.kvcodes.com/2015/12/get-attachments-wordpress/) to get it.